# Using gsub or grep on factors in columns of data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame column that looks something like this:

```
>df[,2]

A    
10
10.1
10a
10a.1
12a.6
13b
17
3c.3
```

Except the column is about 70,000 rows. I want to find and remove all decimals that occur only at the ends of the factors in the column.

Basically, how do I implement the 'grep()' or 'gsub()' functions correctly?

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to find and remove all decimals that occur only at the ends of the factors in the column."? do you want to make `10.1` to `10`, or `10.` to `10`?

Comment: 10.1 to 10, 10a.1 to 10a, 12a.6 to 12a, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doneskis:

```
x <- c("10","10.1","10a","10a.1","12a.6","13b","17","3c.3")
gsub("\\..+$","",x)
#[1] "10"  "10"  "10a" "10a" "12a" "13b" "17"  "3c"
```

To give some explanation: `.` in regular expressions represents 'any character', so to search for an actual period/dot in text (`"."`), you need to escape it with `\\` - i.e. `\\.`

So the `gsub` call finds a period `\\.` , followed by any character or repeats of any character `.+` , followed by the end of the string `$`

Comment: Nice! Works perfect. Can you explain a bit about what the "\\..+$" do? Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again. That "$" is crucial because there are some data points that look like 13.1a.1 that need to be 13.1a so your method took care of it. Boss stuff!

Answer (score 1):

original answer (unchecked)

```
unlist(strsplit(df[,2], split='.', fixed=TRUE))[[1]]
```

edited per suggestion from @thelatemail

```
sapply(strsplit(x,"\\."),"[",1)
```

Comment: I only get "10" returned from this - how's about this?: `sapply(strsplit(x,"\\."),"[",1)`